Unable to add inner shadow to a SwiftUI view
I have seen various questions about this but none seem to answer using inner and drop shadows in any SwiftUI View.
Let's say one has a view (which I am representing with the Shape subclass RoundRectangle. Because it's a Shape, I can trivially add inner and drop shadows like this:
#Preview {
    VStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            // inner shadow
            .fill(.shadow(.inner(color: .white, radius: 1, y: -1)))
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 100)
            // drop shadow
            .shadow(radius: 10)
        Spacer()
    }
    .background(.yellow)
    .padding()
}

The code above produces this:

Now, what if one had a Text view? The drop shadow can be trivially applied but not so the inner one because Text is not a Shape and .fill cannot be called. I have seen solutions that use .overlay but these assume a Shape like Rectangle. Also, they assume the Shape's color is non-clear (e.g. .red or .blue).
#Preview {
    VStack {
        Text("View")
            .background(.blue)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.shadow(.inner(color: .white, radius: 1, y: -1)))
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 100)
        Spacer()
    }
    .background(.yellow)
    .padding()
}

In fact, overlay in this specific code does not really work:

So, how can one apply that .fill(.shadow(.inner(radius:))) to create the inner shadow, assuming any SwiftUI view?

You'd wanna set up the shape inside a mask. The mask is used to confine the inner shadow effect to the bounds of the shape, in this case a Rounded Rectangle. Play around with how the radius, coordinates, and LinearGradient are applied, but I think this is the approach you're looking for:
struct InnerShadow: ViewModifier {
    var color: Color = .black
    var radius: CGFloat = 10
    var x: CGFloat = -5
    var y: CGFloat = -5
    var shadowOpacity: CGFloat = 0.5

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(height: 100)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius)
                    .stroke(color.opacity(shadowOpacity), lineWidth: radius)
                    .blur(radius: radius)
                    .offset(x: x, y: y)
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius)
                        .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [color, .clear], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)))
                        // You can use either of these: 
                        // .fill(.shadow(.inner(color: .white, radius: 1, y: -1)))
                        // .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [color, .clear], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            )
            .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius))
    }
}

#Preview {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        ZStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .modifier(InnerShadow(color: .black))
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}


do you know why stroke is needed? I see much of the shadow is depending on the lineWidth.

Without the stroke the shape does not have a defined border and blur modifier applies to the entire shape, applying the blur to the space of the shape and not the edges.
